# Mathematical result for one-loop diagram of $\phi^3$ theory in four dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, perturbation-theory

The one-loop diagram in $\phi^3$ theory in four dimensions gives the following integral (I have suppressed factors of $2\pi$)
\begin{equation}
\tag{0}
\Gamma(s) = \Gamma(p^2) = \int {d^4 k} \frac{1}{[(p+k)^2- \mu^2 + i\epsilon]}\frac{1}{[k^2 -\mu^2 +i \epsilon]}
\end{equation}
It can be shown that
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\text{Im}\{\Gamma(s)\} &= \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\Gamma(s+i\epsilon) - \Gamma(s-i\epsilon)\bigg)\\
&= \frac{\lambda^2}{2} \int d^4 k (-2\pi i)^2 \delta((p+k)^2 - \mu^2)\delta(k^2-\mu^2)
\end{align}
Now for the first part I use Feynman parameterization to write
\begin{align}
\Gamma(s) &= \int d^4 k \int_0^1 dx \frac{1}{(k^2 + p^2 x(1-x) - \mu^2 + i\epsilon)^2}\\
&= \int d^4 k \int_0^1 dx \frac{1}{(k^2 + s
 x(1-x) - \mu^2 + i\epsilon)^2}
\end{align}
Writing $x(1-x) = \alpha$ and taking the imaginary part of the integrand gives us
\begin{align}
\text{Im}\bigg[\frac{1}{(k^2 + s\alpha -\mu^2 + i\epsilon)^2} \bigg] &= \text{Im}\bigg[\frac{1}{(k^2 + s\alpha -\mu^2)^2 + 2i\epsilon}\bigg]\\
&= -\frac{2 \epsilon}{(k^2+ s\alpha -\mu^2)^4 + \epsilon^2}
\end{align}
where I have absorbed $(k^2 + s\alpha -\mu^2)$ into $\epsilon$ in the first line as $\epsilon$ is very small.
I am not getting the same form for the sum in (1) and am ending up with factors of $i$ everywhere. Is there an easier way to prove this? For the second part I start with (0) and take the imaginary part to get the imaginary part of the integrand:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\epsilon(k^2-\mu^2 + (p+k)^2-\mu^2)}{((p+k)^2 -\mu^2) + \epsilon^2)((k^2-\mu^2)^2+\epsilon^2)}
\end{equation}
Now I know that
\begin{equation}
\delta(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}
\end{equation}
But the form for the integrand is a bit different. Playing around a bit I see that it has the 'properties' to be the delta function product in (0) but I am not sure if my 'method' is rigorous enough. Is there a better way to do this too?

Comment: I don't understand the first line of Eq. 1. Strictly speaking, as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ the RHS vanishes if $\Gamma(s)$ is continuous at $\Gamma(s)$. Don't you mean something like $\operatorname{Im}\Gamma(s) = (\Gamma(s) - \Gamma^*(s))/(2i)$?

Comment: @Aaron its not continuous, there is a branch cut.

Comment: Do you have a reference/rationale for Eq. 1? Based on your second argument, the integrand doesn't seem to be a (product of) delta functions. In particular, that function does not diverge when $(p+k)^2-\mu^2 = 0$ and $k^2 - \mu^2 = 0$, as one needs for a delta function.